# Which of these two loops is faster?

Tags: c, windows, performance, x86, 64-bit

I need to iterate through a set of bytes, searching for a 4 byte value (all 4 bytes are the same). The length of the data is variable and these bytes can be anywhere inside the data; I'm looking for the first instance. I'm trying to find the fastest possible implementation because this logic runs in a critical part of my code.

This will only ever run on x86 & x64, under Windows.

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;
typedef Byte* BytePtr;
typedef unsigned int UInt32;
typedef UInt32* UInt32Ptr;

const Byte MARKER_BYTE = 0xAA;
const UInt32 MARKER = 0xAAAAAAAA;

UInt32 nDataLength = ...;
BytePtr pData = ...;
BytePtr pEnd = pData + nDataLength - sizeof ( UInt32 );

// Option 1 -------------------------------------------
while ( pData < pEnd )
{
    if ( *( (UInt32Ptr) pData ) == MARKER )
    {
        ... // Do something here
        break;
    }

    pData++;
}

// Option 2 -------------------------------------------
while ( pData < pEnd )
{
    if ( ( *pData == MARKER_BYTE ) && ( *( (UInt32Ptr) pData ) == MARKER ) )
    {
        ... // Do something here
        break;
    }

    pData++;
}
```

I think `Option 2` is faster but I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct.

`Option 1` first reads 4 bytes from memory, checks it against the 4-byte constant and if not found, it steps onto the next byte and starts over. The next 4-byte ready from memory is going to overlap 3 bytes already read so the same bytes need to be fetched again. Most bytes before my 4-byte marker would be read twice.

`Option 2` only reads 1 byte at a time and if that single byte is a match, it reads the full 4-byte value from that address. This way, all bytes are read only once and only the 4 matching bytes are read twice.

Is my reasoning correct or am I overlooking something?

And before someone brings it up, yes, I really do need to perform this kind of optimization. :)

**Edit**: note, that this code will only ever run on Intel / AMD based computers. I don't care if other architectures would fail to run this, as long as normal x86 / x64 computers (desktops / servers) run this without problems or performance penalties.

**Edit 2**: compiler is VC++ 2008, if that helps.

Comment: Have you actually tried running the code yourself to compare?  It seems like this is pretty compiler and machine dependent.

Comment: The second loop is going to incur penalties for misaligned access.  Whether those are greater than the cost of ensuring you don't do misaligned access is debatable, but you must measure.  That's the only way you'll ever know for sure.

Comment: Both loops have buffer overrun of course, but I guess you skipped that detail in this sample code

Comment: You could read 4 bytes at a time, aligned, and do `*(UInt32Ptr)pData ^ 0xAAAAAAAA` to check if there was a possibility of the marker starting in that block of 4. Only if so would you need to do unaligned access. But you are going to want to time this.

Comment: I haven't measured this yet, but I also wanted to see if my reasoning is bad.

Comment: You could use this trick: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord  (actually the one below, "Determine if a word has a byte equal to n", but the link to that one doesn't work)

Comment: I think your `typedef` syntax is backwards.

Comment: @Gabriel lol, yes, that could be, I only ran it through the Firefox compiler. :) Hope it still makes sense.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, I didn't, thanks for pointing it out. I didn't notice it.

Comment: What is the Firefox compiler?  You have your question tagged as C.

Comment: @Gabriel lol, I just typed it in Firefox. This wasn't copy & paste of existing code - I wanted to ask the question before implementing this, so I typed up the example, hence the error. I already corrected it above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also try the Boyer-Moore approach.

```
pData = start + 3;
int i;

while(pData < pEnd) {
    for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (*(pData-i) != MARKER_BYTE) {
            pData += 4-i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == 4) {
        /* do something here with (pData-3) */
        break;
    }
}
```

If you're lucky, that tests only every fourth byte until you found a match.

Whether that's faster or slower than testing every single byte is anybody's guess for short patterns as this.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 will do lots of unaligned memory access. I'm not sure if this is even possible for the hardware. At least on some hardware Windows will intercept the resulting exception and, very slowly, emulate the memory access. A total disaster for performance.

Anyway, you have the code already. Why don't you measure it and be 100% sure?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible that any x86 / x64 hardware wouldn't support unaligned access? I've never seen that before. I'm not at all interested in any other architecture, so as long as normal Intel / AMD-based computers work with this code, it's fine. (Assuming I don't incur heavy penalties for unaligned access - this is the reason I posted the question.)

Comment: It is supporting it in all cases but at a terrible performance cost.

Comment: Is it better to just read 4 individual bytes in 4 consecutive reads? I cannot ensure aligned access because my marker can be anywhere within the data.

Comment: That's only a problem on IA64 or when doing 16+ byte accesses though. Alignment shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: Yes, try this: (pData[0] | pData[1] << 8 | pData[1] << 16 | pData[1] << 24) == MARKER; Also try lots of variations ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Option 2.
There's no reason to fetch 4 bytes if 255 out of 256 times the first one will not be the one you want.

And for Pete's sake, unroll the loop.

EDIT: Unrolling. The length is `nDataLength`. You could say this:

```
pEnd1 = pData + (nDataLength & -8);
while (pData < pEnd1){
  if (pData[0] == theByteIWant){ ... }
  if (pData[1] == theByteIWant){ ... }
  ...
  if (pData[7] == theByteIWant){ ... }
  pData += 8;
}
while(pData < pEnd){
  if (pData[0] == theByteIWant){ ... }
  pData++;
}
```

See what that does? You don't spend half your time asking a question `(pData < pEnd)` for which the answer is nearly always the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean unroll the loop? I know what it means but I'm not sure how would I do it here - my data size is not known ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not complete, but the essential idea is to search eight (8) bytes at a time for the 0xAA pattern.  If found, then you can perform a secondary search for the MARKER pattern.

Phase 1: Do a byte by byte test until your array is 8-byte aligned.

Phase 2:
    #define HAS_NUL_BYTE(x) ((x) - 0x0101010101010101ull) & ~x & 0x8080808080808080ull)

```
uint64_t  value;
for (...) {
    value = *(uint64_t *) array[i] ^ 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAull;
    if (HAS_NUL_BYTE (value) != 0) {
        perform secondary search for the MARKER pattern
    }
    i += 8;
}
```

This approach should (hopefully) have the following advantages.

1. 1 comparison per 8 bytes instead of 8 when 0xAA is not in the window.
2. Fewer mis-aligned memory accesses.

Downsides include ...

1. It's more complicated
2. If the array contains a lot of 0xAA bytes (but not the MARKER), false positives in the primary search will impact performance.

One other thing--since you mention that this will only run on an x86-64 under windows, have you considered writing this in assembly?  If so, the PCMPEQB instruction might prove useful.

Hope this helps.